# Attribute error using python3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

i'm a beginner in python, i'm using python 3x, i'm getting an `'attribute error' : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isdigit'` on line 4 of my program.
*Q: Use a "forever" while loop to get user input of integers to add to sum, 
   until a non-digit is entered, then break the loop and print sum* .Here is the program :

```
sum = 0
num=""
while True:
    num=print("input no. :")
    if num.isdigit():
        sum=sum+int(num)
    else:
        break
print("sum is :",sum)
```

what must be the modification  to be done to modify the program.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

`num = print("input no. :")`

`print` simply prints, it has no return value. You are looking for `input`:

`num = input("input no. :")`

As a side note, `sum` is a built-in function and it is not a good idea to overwrite it, so pick another name for `sum`.